# Extract only the amino acid residues on the surface of protein structure data

Tags: bioinformatics, chimera

I'd like to use protein structure data from PDBs visualized by Chimera to do two things. I'd be happy to learn the appropriate tools and methods.

・Mapping information about amino acids present on protein surfaces to sequences

・Find the charges of exposed amino acids on the surface and apply color gradations to the amino acid molecules according to their values

The second one in particular looks like it could be done with Chimera's "Coulomb surface coloring". But I'm not sure what kind of value to enter underneath the color and how to find it, which is needed to add a gradient.

Sorry for my bad English ...

Answer (score 1):

As for the first part, you would need to choose a definition of "on the surface", which is probably something like solvent accessible surface area, then write a script to find all the amino acids that exceed a certain threshold according to this metric. Chimera highlights selected amino acids in the "sequence" window, so if your script selects everything that exceeds your threshold then you have them highlighted.

As for the second part, all amino acids are either neutral, positively charged, or negatively charged, where "charged" really means "when they ionize". Depending on the pH and the local environment, the percentage of the time they actually *are* ionized (and hence charged) varies--though generally aside from histidine (which ionizes near physiological pH) and maybe cysteine, most of the charged amino acids are significantly ionized in the cell. But all negative amino acids have a -1 charge and all positive ones have a +1 charge, there's no -2 or +2 or higher. So when you plot "gradations" as you say, you're plotting the *electric potential* at a given point on the surface of the protein resulting from the sum effect of all charged amino acids nearby, weighted by their distance away according to a modified form of Coulomb's law that takes into account the shielding effect of water (which is very substantial).

The numerical values that map electric potential magnitude to colors are arbitrary and a matter of clarity and aesthetic taste--you want to set them such that the values over the surface get mapped to as much of your color range as possible, without too many extreme values getting "clipped" at either end, so that the full extent of the variation is captured. Finding that is just by trial and error.